# Get the last row in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
    s.last_spread, s.sd, s.mean, s.id
    ,c.id_ticker, c.coef
    ,t.ticker
    ,/*p.last,*/ p.price

FROM (SELECT * FROM spreads WHERE spreads.id_check=1 LIMIT 60,896) as s 

    INNER JOIN coef as c 
        ON c.id_spread = s.id

    INNER JOIN tickers AS t
            ON t.id = c.id_ticker

    LEFT JOIN (SELECT prices.id_ticker, MAX(prices.date) as last, prices.price FROM prices GROUP BY prices.id_ticker) AS p
            ON p.id_ticker = t.id

ORDER BY s.id, c.id
```

the last JOIN doesn't return the correct value....I need to get the LAST PRICE of the tickers (so the last row of each ticker).

At the moment it returns the first price, how can I change the entire query to get the last prices of each ticker.id ? (`p.id_ticker = t.id`)

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add a order by to this subquery:

```
SELECT prices.id_ticker, MAX(prices.date) as last, prices.price 
FROM prices GROUP BY prices.id_ticker 
order by prices.id_ticker desc
```

Comment: @jurgend is it possible to optimize it? (i'm referring to the indexes or other?)

Answer (score 2):

Using A having clause would be elegant:

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT prices.id_ticker, prices.date as last, prices.price FROM prices GROUP BY prices.id_ticker HAVING prices.date = MAX(prices.date) )
```

**Edit:** But it does **NOT** work... (see comments below)

Comment: @Argeman yes it is elegant...but I tried it and it does not work, p.last and p.price return NULL, how can i fix it?

Comment: @Dail You are correct, it doesn't work. It can only work for the id_ticker with the biggest overall date! Sorry...

Answer (score 1):

I would say use `ORDER BY` and a `LIMIT` to get only one price (the last price).